# wordpress slidedeck plugin - javascript not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a HTML 5 Reset Wordpress Theme as a framework for a project. The problem I'm having is with a plugin - slidedeck - that doesn't work, more precisely, the javascript doesn't load.

This is the link to the website: http://melisayavas.com/web (on the homepage the text should slide).

This is what I have in my functions.php:

```
// Load jQuery
  if ( !function_exists(core_mods) ) {
     function core_mods() {
        if ( !is_admin() ) {
          wp_deregister_script('jquery');
          wp_register_script('jquery', ("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
          wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
           }
         }
           core_mods();
       }
```

In header.php the only script I have is this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/modernizr-1.7.min.js">
```

And then in footer.php I have this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to work with javascript / jQuery, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or how should I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you used

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', ("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

and as a result you got this error

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

because

`http://melisayavas.com/web//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js?`
 is an invalid url so jQuery is undefined

you can solve it  by changing the url to (notice `http:`)

```
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
```

**Note:** Use `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js` to always get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

also important to note that WordPress 3.6 busted some SlideDeck features so be sure to upgrade SlideDeck to 2.3.3

For more, see http://www.slidedeck.com/blog/news-updates/wordpress-3-6-making-your-slidedecks-cry-no-problem/